# How to validate username TextFormField when incorrect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to validate my form on login button press. It works perfectly fine on client side when all fields are empty however with my switch/case it does not appear to work. I believe it may be related to my validation function but I cannot pinpoint it. I believe the booleans are being set correctly in MySOAPRequest since when I press the login button then update the company or pin field the error message shows on the username field but it should show on login button press.

**Login page with text fields and login button**

```
                          CustomTextField(
                            key: _customTextFieldKey,
                            companyController: _companyController,
                            usernameController: _usernameController,
                            pinController: _pinController,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          OutlinedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                              String lcomp = Globals().lcomp =
                                  _companyController.text.trim();
                              String luser = Globals().luser =
                                  _usernameController.text.trim();
                              String lpin =
                                  Globals().lpin = _pinController.text.trim();

                              if (lcomp.isNotEmpty &&
                                  luser.isNotEmpty &&
                                  lpin.isNotEmpty &&
                                  !_customTextFieldKey.currentState!
                                      .hasError()) {
                                MySOAPRequest(
                                  lcomp: lcomp,
                                  luser: luser,
                                  lpin: lpin,
                                  onLoginSuccess: _saveCredentials,
                                ).makeSOAPRequest(context);
                              } else {
                                _customTextFieldKey.currentState?.validate();
                              }
                            },
                            child: const Text('Login'),
                          ),
```

**MySOAPRequest page code**

```
  final String lcomp;
  final String luser;
  final String lpin;
  final Function(bool) onLoginSuccess; // define the onLoginSuccess parameter

  MySOAPRequest({
    required this.lcomp,
    required this.luser,
    required this.lpin,
    required this.onLoginSuccess,
  });

switch (logonState) {
        case '1':
          // Navigate to the Landing page if the logon state is 1
          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
          loginFlushbar(context);
          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
          navigateToSubPages(context);
          onLoginSuccess(true);
          break;
        case '3':
          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
          flushbar(context, 'Incorrect User Name',
              'Please try again or contact your administrator if this issue persists.');
          onLoginSuccess(false);
          break;
            default:
          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
          flushbar(context, 'Unknown Error',
              'An unknown error occurred. Please try again or contact your administrator.');
              Globals().usernameHasError = true;
          Globals().errorText = 'Incorrect User Name';
          Globals().customTextFieldKey.currentState?.validate();
          onLoginSuccess(false);
          break;
      }
```

**Username field text**

```
class CustomTextFieldState extends State<CustomTextField> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  //final _usernameKey = Globals().customTextFieldKey;

  String _company = '';
  String _username = '';
  String _pin = '';

  bool _companyHasError = false;
  bool _usernameHasError = false;
  bool _pinHasError = false;

  bool hasError() {
    return _usernameHasError || _companyHasError || _pinHasError;
  }

  void validate() {
    setState(() {
      if (_formKey.currentState != null) {
        _companyHasError =
            !_formKey.currentState!.validate() || _company.isEmpty;
        _usernameHasError =
            !_formKey.currentState!.validate() || _username.isEmpty;
        _pinHasError = !_formKey.currentState!.validate() || _pin.isEmpty;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String lcomp = widget.companyController.text.trim();

    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0),
            //!--- COMPANY TEXT FIELD --- //

            child: TextFormField(
              controller: widget.companyController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Color(0xff185C91),
                  ),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: ThemeClass.primaryColor,
                  ),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(
                    color: Color(0xff185C91),
                  ),
                ),
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                ),
                disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x00232323)),
                ),
                suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.corporate_fare_outlined,
                    color: ThemeClass.primaryColor),
                labelText: "Company Name",
                labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                ),
                hintText: 'Enter Company Name',
                hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                ),
                errorText: _companyHasError
                    ? 'Please enter a valid company name!'
                    : ((_company.isNotEmpty &&
                            !Globals().resultList.contains(lcomp))
                        ? 'Please enter a valid company name!'
                        : null),
              ),
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter your company name!';
                }
                return null;
              },
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _company = value;
                  _companyHasError = false;
                });
              },
              onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _companyHasError = !_formKey.currentState!.validate();
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          //!--- END COMPANY TEXT FIELD --- //

          //!--- USERNAME TEXT FIELD --- //
          TextFormField(
            controller: widget.usernameController,
            //key: _usernameKey,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff185C91),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: ThemeClass.primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff185C91),
                ),
              ),
              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x00232323)),
              ),
              suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person_outlined,
                  color: ThemeClass.primaryColor),
              labelText: "Username",
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter username',
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
              ),
              errorText: _usernameHasError
                  ? 'Please enter a valid username!'
                  : Globals().usernameHasError
                      ? Globals().errorText
                      : null,
            ),
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your username!';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _username = value;
                _usernameHasError = false;
                Globals().usernameHasError = false;
              });
            },
            onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _usernameHasError = !_formKey.currentState!.validate();
              });
            },
          ),
          //!--- END USERNAME TEXT FIELD --- //

          const SizedBox(height: 20),

          //!--- PIN TEXT FIELD --- //
          TextFormField(
            controller: widget.pinController,
            inputFormatters: [
              LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
              FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
            ],
            obscureText: true,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff185C91),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: ThemeClass.primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(
                  color: Color(0xff185C91),
                ),
              ),
              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0x00232323)),
              ),
              suffixIcon: const Icon(Icons.pin_outlined,
                  color: ThemeClass.primaryColor),
              labelText: "PIN",
              labelStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              ),
              hintText: 'Enter PIN',
              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
              ),
              errorText: _pinHasError
                  ? 'Please enter a valid PIN!'
                  : _pin.length < 4 && _pin.isNotEmpty
                      ? 'PIN is too short!'
                      : null,
            ),
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            validator: (value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter your PIN!';
              }
              return null;
            },
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _pin = value;
                _pinHasError = false;
              });
            },
            onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _pinHasError = !_formKey.currentState!.validate();
              });
            },
          ),
          //!--- END PIN TEXT FIELD --- //
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `TextFormField` in a `Form` widget and provide a `GlobalKey<FormState>` to the `Form` as its key. Then you can validate it with `_formKey.currentState!.validate()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already have the `TextFormField` wrapped inside a `Form` widget with a `GlobalKey<FormState>`. The validation function is shown in the username field code above. When validating on button press it only sets my booleans to true in the switch case. Only when the other 2 fields are altered does it then show the error message.

Answer (score 1):

i just saw something bad you are doing on the switch case,

```
  ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
```

there is a reason why you should not call the build context asynchronously, it may have been unmounted since you passed it aroud

if you are using a stateful widget, which appears to be so, you can define your context dependendant functions outside the build widget like this

```
 StatefulWidget{

 void _loginFlushBar() => loginFlushbar(context);
 void _navigateToSubPages => navigateToSubPages(context);



   Widget build(Buildcontext context){
      //Your widgets
   }

}
```

Comment: The flushbar is only there temporarily to be sure the switch case works. Once the validation is on the text field the flushbars will be removed although I was curious about how to resolve that. I am not using a stateful widget though. I will update the code to show this.